# what am i misunderstanding here?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit and Foote p.161

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $n>1$.
>
> Let $n={p_1}^{a_1}\cdots {p_k}^{a_k}$ be the prime factorzation.
>
> Then, $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{a^1}}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{{p_k}^{a^k}}$

Doesn't this mean that there is a unique abelian group of order $n$ up to isomorphism?

What am i misunderstanding here?

Comment: This is obviously false: $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Are you sure to have reported the statement correctly?

Comment: Please explain your confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement in Dummit and Foote says

$$G \cong A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_k,\text{ where } |A_i| = p_i^{\alpha_i}.$$

It does not say $A_i \cong \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{\alpha_i}\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, there can be many abelian groups of the same prime-powered order, for example $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer of @rghthndsd: I think you're confusing the two statements of the cited theorem.  The first statement is exactly as in @rghthndsd 's response.  The second statement is for each of the $A \in \{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ as above with $|A| = p^\alpha$,
$$
A \cong Z_{p^{\beta_1}} \times \cdots \times Z_{p^{\beta_t}}
$$
with $\beta_1 \geq \cdots \geq \beta_t \geq 1$ and $\sum_i \beta_i = \alpha$.

Comment: This is a comment not adding anything new to RightHndSds post.

Comment: @amWhy Huh? The cited result in Dummit and Foote has three distinct statements. The OP posted a jumbled version that conflated the first two. RightHndSd gave a corrected version of the first statement; I gave the second. So my answer does in fact add something new that is not in the other answer.

Answer (score -2):

The prime factors does not have to be unique.